# Sitecore Instance https Url not accessible on docker

Tags: docker

After Setup Sitecore Helix from https://github.com/Sitecore/Helix.Examples. I am able to access Sitecore instance using container IP address but instance are not accessible as https://cm.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/

for this I did change in hosts file by replacing 127.0.0.1 with container IP address, but still url not accessible neither **http://cm.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/** nor **https://cm.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/** way.

Steps which followed during setup

1. cloned **Helix.Examples** repo
2. only changed port for `solr` service in `docker-compose.yml` to avoid conflict
3. `docker-compose up -d`
4. success and on dashboard containers are running
5. while accessing `https://cm.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/` getting error on page: "This site can’t be reached"
6. but able to access sitecore page using container IP address

Please let me know if I am missing any steps.

Comment: Can you post your `.env` file? Have you verified the host you specified is exactly the same between your hosts file, your browser, and your `.env` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to check your .env file at your project root. In this file you can setup many things such as :

```
CD_HOST=cd.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/
CM_HOST=cm.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/
ID_HOST=id.basic-company-unicorn.localhost/
```

There is probably something in there already.

For the http vs https, Traefik is acting as a proxy here, and you can see on each services that has a labels node containing these:

```yml
"traefik.enable=true"
"traefik.http.routers.id-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
"traefik.http.routers.id-secure.rule=Host(`${ID_HOST}`)"
"traefik.http.routers.id-secure.tls=true"
```

So by default you should be on https, if I am not mistaken.